# Symfony include partial from custom folder

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, partial-views, partial

Form example:

```
<?php include_partial('job/list', array('jobs' => $jobs)) ?>
```

I have module **job** and partial **_list.php** in module folder **templates**.
Is it possible create in **templates** folder **partials** and in include all partials from that folder? If it possible how to make it? Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Create a '**_partials**' folder in the **templates** directory in your module
2. Create a '**list.php**' in the '_partials' folder, ie '**modules/job/templates/_partials/list.php**'
3. Call it as:

   `<?php include_partial('job/partials/list', array('jobs' => $jobs))?>`